# Map a key that only works in Visual Block mode

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

However I'm using [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plugin, and I'd like map <kbd>I</kbd> to <kbd>C-n</kbd> and map <kbd>A</kbd> to <kbd>C-n / Space</kbd> when I'm in Visual Block mode.

I've tried something like this:

```
:vmap I <C-n>
:vmap A <C-n><Space>
```

And it works fine, but it also works in *any visual mode*.

So how can I map a key that only works in Visual Block mode?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that you check what those two specific keys do in Visual Block mode before overwriting their default behaviour.

Comment: @vitor, who cares? Vim is useless without plugins, right? (sarcasm, just in case).

Comment: :'D @romainl nothing that `n` and `.` wouldn't be able to solve in this case, right?

Comment: @Vitor Good idea, let me check it :P

Comment: @Vitor However I've checked the document of vim-multiple-cursors again and I can only found the *main cursor_next_key* `g:multi_cursor_next_key`. So when I press this key in Visual Block mode the plugin will start, but I really can't just change this(if I did it then I will not be able to use `A` and `I`).

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Correct! I've just checked the document, it says: `x  Visual mode map. Defined using ':xmap' or ':xnoremap'.`, but I don't understand...what's the deference between `xmap` and `vmap`?

Comment: @KevinGuan vmap works in visual and select modes, xmap - only in visual

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Understand now, thanks a lot :)